# Firebase Firestore displaying simpler URL for SubSubCollection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I am very new to SPAs (Single Page Applications) and noSQL coding, but I am very interested in these topics!

I do have experience with PHP, mySQL & relational Databases which is messing with my mindset when developing with a noSQL database.

I am currently developing a webapp where i create a collection called 'campaigns'.
This collection has a subcollection called 'categories'.
Which has another subcollection called 'notes'.

The Firestore setup is like this:

```
 Campaigns
   campaign1
     Categories
       category1
         Notes
           note1
           note2

   campaign2
     Categories
       category1
         Notes
           note1
           note2
```

At the moment when I want to display **note1** I have to create the URL like this:

```
domain.com/campaigns/Wi8AyzYgpKCnTXvCL9SV/categories/XlsMW4a8YRoLC1t3NbWG/notes/wg5oGQIZ8EOSYdFVOIlB
```

This seems a bit overkill.

Is there a way to shorten it to something like this:

```
domain.com/notes/wg5oGQIZ8EOSYdFVOIlBm
```

I know this can be done in a relational database, but I don't know if it can be done with Firestore

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to have a flat `notes` root collection with all the notes documents which have a `campaign` and `category` fields.

This way you can directly extract the document id from an url like `domain.com/notes/wg5oGQIZ8EOSYdFVOIlBm`. If you want to query for a specific campaign or category or a specific campaign/category couple, you just use a `where()` query (or a combination of tho `where()`s).

In terms of performance it will make no difference compare to a sub-collection approach as described in your question: the execution time for a query depends on the number of docs returned by the query.

Comment: Hi @RasmusJustesen, did you have time to look at the proposed solution?